# Invoke Excel Solver through a VBA *function* rather than a sub/macro

Tags: excel, vba, function, solver

I am trying to invoke the Excel Solver tool through a VBA interface.

Specifically, I would like to invoke the Solver functionality directly from a cell, in the same way I would use any user-defined function.

Using online help, I implemented the following "proof-of-concept" basic `Sub` / macro.

```
Sub mySolverSub()
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="C4", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=2, ByChange:="C3"
SolverSolve (True)
End Sub
```

and can invoke this macro using a button or in the immediate window. It works correctly and gives cells C3 and C4 the correct values (assuming cell C4 has a meaningful formula).

However, I have been unable to implement the same concept in a `Function`.

For example, I tried

```
Function mySolverF()
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="C4", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=2, ByChange:="C3"
SolverSolve (True)
mySolverF = Range("C3").Value
End Function
```

My intended usage would be to type this function in a cell, say in Cell C5, and have Solver then determine the values of cells C3 and C4, and for Cell C5 to have the same value as Cell C3. This would be much more convenient/scalable than having to create and push macro buttons.

However this function `mySolverF` does not work when used in the spreadsheet. On earlier versions of Excel it gives the error message "*Solver: An unexpected internal error occurred, or available memory was exhausted*". On later versions of Excel there is no error message but the function does not actually change anything and just returns the current value of Cell C3 - i.e. Solver does not run.

Interestingly the function `mySolverF` does work correctly when called from a sub, e.g.

```
Sub mySolverSub2()
res = mySolverF()
MsgBox "mySolverSub2:res=" & res
End Sub
```

but this is not quite what I want, because it still requires creating + pushing a button instead of being invoked automatically like a proper function.

Any idea what is going wrong?

thanks in advance!

---

PS: Note that I would specifically like to interface to Solver rather than implement the numerical algorithm itself in VBA.

Comment: I believe this is an issue with Solver itself... Solver shouldn't be able to be in a function as it actually changes a cell value when it executed.  As a function cannot change a cell value, it cannot invoke Solver via a function in the spreadsheet.  The rationale for it working as a function called within a subroutine is that you're maintaining all of the data in allocated memory, not outputting to a cell (specific to using the UDF in a cell), which then allows the subroutine to output that expression as needed.

Comment: The solution/workaround would be to write a function that performs the Solver functionality, where it can output as needed, rather than how Solver specifically replaces a cell value.

Comment: You could use the worksheet_change (and calculate) events to run your Solver method.

Comment: Thank you Cyril and Tim - this information makes good sense. Thank you also for suggesting useful workarounds. 

Probably using `worksheet_change` is closest in spirit to what I had in mind, as it still employs Solver albeit in a more manual way. 

Implementing my own Solver-like functionality in VBA could also work but is not so easy / time-efficient when using more advanced features such as multiple decision variables and  constraints.